# How do I make a material show up on a sphere

Tags: three.js

```
// set the scene size
var WIDTH = 1650,
    HEIGHT = 700;

// set some camera attributes
var VIEW_ANGLE = 100,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 0.1,
    FAR = 10000;

// get the DOM element to attach to
// - assume we've got jQuery to hand
var $container = $('#container');

// create a WebGL renderer, camera
// and a scene
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                                ASPECT,
                                NEAR,
                                FAR  );

//camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ));

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
camera.position.x = 200;
camera.position.y = 200;
camera.position.z = 300;


// start the renderer
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

// attach the render-supplied DOM element
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

// create the sphere's material
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
{
    color: 0xCC0000
});

// set up the sphere vars
var radius = 60, segments = 20, rings = 20;

// create a new mesh with sphere geometry -
// we will cover the sphereMaterial next!
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings),
   img);

// add the sphere to the scene
scene.add(sphere);

// and the camera
scene.add(camera);

// create a point light
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );

// set its position
pointLight.position.x = 50;
pointLight.position.y = 100;
pointLight.position.z = 180;

// add to the scene
scene.add(pointLight);

// add a base plane
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500,8, 8);
var planeMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x666699});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);

plane.position.x = 160;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = 20;

//rotate it to correct position
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add(plane);

// add 3D img

var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cube.png')
});
img.map.needsUpdate = true;

// draw!
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I've put the var img as a material to the sphere but everytime I render it aoutomaticly    changes color...
How do I do so it just will have the image as I want... not all the colors?
I whould possibly put the img on a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the callback of the loadTexture function. If you refer to the [source of `THREE.ImageUtils`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js) you will see that the loadTexture function is defined as

```
loadTexture: function ( url, mapping, onLoad, onError ) {

        var image = new Image();
        var texture = new THREE.Texture( image, mapping );

        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

        loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

            texture.image = event.content;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            if ( onLoad ) onLoad( texture );

        } );

        loader.addEventListener( 'error', function ( event ) {

            if ( onError ) onError( event.message );

        } );

        loader.crossOrigin = this.crossOrigin;
        loader.load( url, image );

        return texture;

    },
```

Here, only the url parameter is required. The texture mapping can be passed in as null. The last two parameters are the callbacks. You can pass in a function for each one which will be called at the respective load and error events. The problem you are experiencing is most likely caused by the fact that three.js is attempting to apply your material before your texture is properly loaded. In order to remedy this, you should only do this inside a function passed as the onLoad callback (which will only be called after the image has been loaded up). Also, you should always create your material before you apply it to an object.

So you should change your code from:

```
// set up the sphere vars
var radius = 60, segments = 20, rings = 20;

// create a new mesh with sphere geometry -
// we will cover the sphereMaterial next!
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings),
   img);

// add the sphere to the scene
scene.add(sphere);
```

to something like:

```
var sphereGeo, sphereTex, sphereMat, sphereMesh;
var radius = 60, segments = 20, rings = 20;

sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings);
sphereTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cube.png', null, function () {
    sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: sphereTex});
    sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    scene.add(sphereMesh);
});
```