# How do I make a sphere with a texture on it?

Tags: html, three.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a material show up on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781476/how-do-i-make-a-material-show-up-on-a-sphere)

```
// set the scene size
var WIDTH = 1650,
    HEIGHT = 700;

// set some camera attributes
var VIEW_ANGLE = 100,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 0.1,
    FAR = 10000;

// get the DOM element to attach to
// - assume we've got jQuery to hand
var $container = $('#container');

// create a WebGL renderer, camera
// and a scene
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                                ASPECT,
                                NEAR,
                                FAR  );

//camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ));

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
camera.position.x = 200;
camera.position.y = 200;
camera.position.z = 300;


// start the renderer
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

// attach the render-supplied DOM element
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

// create the sphere's material
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
{
    color: 0xCC0000
});
```

I think this is the problem...
Frome here...

```
    var sphereGeo, sphereTex, sphereMat, sphereMesh;
var radius = 60, segments = 20, rings = 20;

sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings);
sphereTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cube.png', null, function () {
    sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: sphereTex});
    sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    scene.add(sphereMesh);
});
```

To here...
Right?

```
// and the camera
scene.add(camera);

// create a point light
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );

// set its position
pointLight.position.x = 50;
pointLight.position.y = 100;
pointLight.position.z = 180;

// add to the scene
scene.add(pointLight);

// add a base plane
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500,8, 8);
var planeMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x666699});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);

plane.position.x = 160;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = 20;

//rotate it to correct position
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add(plane);

// add 3D img

var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cube.png')
});
img.map.needsUpdate = true;

// draw!
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I want to get my img texture up on my sphere... 
Right now it's just a plane black surface the ball does show up but it has no texture so you cant see it... how do I get the texture on the sphere?